# I want the "YOU ENTERED LEVEL X" message to be displayed only once. Please read the full question to understand it better

Tags: javascript, node.js, replit

I need help for this code. Let me tell what the problem is. For example, after running the program , if the score is 4, as soon as user scores 4, it will be printed Congratulations!! You entered level 1 of the game and the same goes for level 2 and level 3 for the score 7 and 9 respectively. Now, the problem is- if user scores 4, then the line will be printed for Level 1 and if user fails to answer the next question, then again this line will be printed. What I want is that the line to be printed only once the user enters the score. I don't want it to be printed again and again if the user fails to pass the score for which the message is written. I hope I am able to explain the problem properly. If you don't get what I am trying to say, please tell me. I'll try to explain my problem more elaborately. Thank You. Below is the code

```
var readlineSync = require('readline-sync');

var userName = readlineSync.question("May we know your name please? ");

console.log("Hello " + userName + " to the neog.camp fun quiz game!!\n");

console.log("Please answer 4 questions correctly to reach Level 1 of the game,7 to reach Level 2 of the game, and 9 to reach Level 3 of the game.\nALL THE BEST :) \n\n");


var currentScore = 0;
var highScores =
{
  azhar: 10,
  bhargav: 7
};

function ask(question, answer) {
  var userAnswer = readlineSync.question(question);
  if (userAnswer === answer) {
    console.log("Correct!!");
    currentScore++;
    console.log("score: ", currentScore);
  }
  else {
    console.log("Wrong!!");
    console.log("score: ", currentScore);
  }
  if(currentScore>=4 && currentScore<5)
     {
    console.log("Congrats!! You entered LEVEL 1 of the game!!")
     }
  if(currentScore>=7 && currentScore<8)
     {
    console.log("Congrats!! You entered LEVEL 2 of the game!!")
     }
  if(currentScore>=9 && currentScore<10)
     {
    console.log("Congrats!! You entered LEVEL 3 of the game!! Yippeee ;) ")
     }
}

var questions =
  [
    {
      question: "What is the capital of INDIA? ",
      answer: "New Delhi"
    },
    {
      question: "What is the full name of MS Dhoni? ",
      answer: "Mahendra Singh Dhoni"
    },
    {
      question: "Who founded Amazon ?",
      answer: "Jeff Bezos"
    },
    {
      question: "Which is the largest country in Asia? ",
      answer: "China"
    },
    {
      question: "How many sides does a quadrilateral have? ",
      answer: "4"
    },
    {
      question: "Which Indian Cricketer did hit six sixes in six balls against England in 2007? ",
      answer: "Yuvraj Singh"
    },
    {
      question: "What is the full form of CS GO? ",
      answer: "Counter Strike Global Offensive"
    },
    {
      question: "How many players are there in a football team excluding the goal keeper? ",
      answer: "10"
    },
    {
      question: "Which language is called the mother of all programming languages?",
      answer: "C"
    },
    {
      question: "What is the name of the highest mountain in the world? ",
      answer: "Mount Everest"
    }
  ];

for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
  var currentQuestion = questions[i];
  ask(currentQuestion.question, currentQuestion.answer);
}



console.log("\nYour final score is : ", currentScore);

if (currentScore >= highScores.azhar) {
  console.log("Congratulations!! You are the new highest scorer!! \t Kindly send the screenshot of the score to us.\nThank You")
}
else {
  console.log("Oops!! You failed to beat the highest scorer!!\nBetter Luck Next Time")
  console.log("High Scores :- \n" + "Azhar : " + highScores.azhar + "\nBhargav : " + highScores.bhargav);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your program outputs the string when the user fails, is because your program will check the score and print the string, regardless of whether the answer is correct or not.

In order to change this you must specify an exit condition in the case where the answer is wrong

```
function ask(question, answer) {
  var userAnswer = readlineSync.question(question);
  if (userAnswer === answer) {
    console.log("Correct!!");
    currentScore++;
    console.log("score: ", currentScore);
  }
  else {
    console.log("Wrong!!");
    console.log("score: ", currentScore);
    return
```

Unrelated to your question, but still an existing bug is the way you use `userName` inside `console.log`. Presently it will output "username" as a string, rather than the value of the variable. This needs to be re-written using backticks as follows:

```
console.log(`Hello ${userName} to the neog.camp fun quiz game!!\n`);
```

Comment: Out of all the suggested answers, this one was very simple and useful too. It worked the way I wanted it to be. Thanks a lot buddy.

Thanks to every other person for their suggestions. Thank You very much :)

Comment: But can you please explain me brother what does only this return keyword do actually? Can you please explain how it worked here?

Comment: In javascript whenever the code reaches the line of `return`, the program will stop executing and get out of the function. In your case, when the user would input a wrong answer your `function ask(question, answer)` would run the `else` component of your `if` statement. It would print `console.log("Wrong!!")` and `console.log("score: ", currentScore)`. However, it would *continue* through your function and check the userscore and print those sentences you wrote depending on the score. The `return` keyword, stops the program from continuing down to those if statements.

Comment: If you can, please mark my answer as correct by pressing the tick-mark at the top left of my response. You can read more about `return` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

Answer (score 0):

I think adding a return statement in the `ask` function after they have entered a wrong answer will do the trick.

```
else {
    console.log("Wrong!!");
    console.log("score: ", currentScore);
    return;   //<-- this line
  }
```

It stops further execution of the `ask` function.

If you would like to refactor that function a bit more, you can do an early return check like this. You won't need the `else` statement, because your function returns early when the answer is wrong.

You can return whatever you like since you are not doing anything with the return value, in this example an `undefined` is returned.

```js
//...
if (userAnswer !== answer) {
    console.log("Wrong!!");
    console.log("score: ", currentScore);
    return;
}
console.log("Correct!!");
currentScore++;
console.log("score: ", currentScore);
```

Comment: Even if I appreciate your attempt of simplification, I'm afraid that saying `it returns null/void` would instill in a beginner the belief that `null` and `undefined` are the same thing

Comment: In this use-case it really doesn't matter, since it's only to stop further execution. Nothing is done with the returned value.  It would have been another solution if the code example was different. But I've updated my answer, to be correct.

Comment: I know, but a beginner would think that `undefined === null` :) SO is full of people that get confused about this, so better being clear

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're looking for something that stores the "state" (I will be murdered by frontend devs for calling it this) of the level.

Storing something like that could be as simple as

```js
let currentLevel = 0 // or 1, depending on where you want them to start
```

With the current code, you would only need to add in an if statement which checks the level

```js
if(currentScore>=4 && currentScore<5 && !currentLevel === 1)
     {
    console.log("Congrats!! You entered LEVEL 1 of the game!!")
    currentLevel = 1
     }
```